# Another prevent double click

Tags: jquery, animation, click

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gWTj9/) I have a simple custom slide-up/slide-down animation (all the credits to ebram tharwat for the code). The problem is... you guessed it: double click. If you click the up/down buttons more than once within 500ms (time the animation takes to complete) it screws everything up.
I've tried the stop(true); and preventDefault but with no avail.
Any help is always truly appreciated.

Sample code:

```
$("#upBtn").on('click', function () {
    // slide all optionMenu_* up by 80px
    var maxUp = ($('div.optionMenu').length - 3) * 90;
    if (parseInt($('.sliderContainerInside').css('top')) - 10 > -maxUp) {
        $('.sliderContainerInside').animate({
            top: parseInt($('.sliderContainerInside').css('top')) - 90 + 'px'
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Thanx.

Pedro

Comment: I think the problem is that you're setting your animation positions based on the current position of the elements, rather than based on some fixed dimensions that are independent of the animation itself.

Comment: @Pedro is it Ok if you changed your "#up" and "Down" into buttons

Comment: Hi ebram. :) I'm not sure... I'm actually using a custom animated "button" with mouseenter/mouseleave/click in my project to trigger the sliding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
var place = 0;
var position = 10;
var limit = parseInt($('div.optionMenu').length) - 3;

$("#upBtn").click(function () {
    // slide all optionMenu_* up by 80px
    if(place > 0) {
        place--;
    }
    animate();
});

$("#downBtn").click(function () {
    // slide all optionMenu_* up by -80px
    if(place < limit) {
        place++;
    }
    animate();
});

function animate() {
    position = 10 - (place*90);
    $('.sliderContainerInside').stop().animate({
        top: position + 'px'
    }, 500);
}
```

Remembers how many times the button was clicked and animates straight to the correct point. Added bonus of not repeating the same code twice.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gWTj9/6/)

Answer (score 1):

check if element `.is(':animated')` and return false; if you want the animation to complete before another can be triggered

```
if($('.sliderContainerInside').is(':animated')){
    return false;   
}
```

Also for the top property you can use `'+=90px'` and `'-=90px'` instead of

```
parseInt($('.sliderContainerInside').css('top')) - 90 + 'px'
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qpdVD/)

Comment: This works in a sense, but it doesn't allow the user to click multiple times to jump further down/up.

Comment: That's good wirey, thank you. As to jmar777's observation, maybe a mousedown/mouseup? What code could we use for a continuous sliding?

Comment: @Pedro check out jmar777's solution below - is that what you're asking for?

Answer (score 1):

I think the most useful approach here would be to `stop` the animation upon a new click, and only listen to the last click. Also, you need to calculate your position based on something other than the current position of the animated element, as that will throw you off when you click in the middle of an animation.

Something like a global variable:

```
var target = 10;

$("#upBtn").on('click', function () {
    // slide all optionMenu_* up by 80px
    var maxUp = ($('div.optionMenu').length - 3) * 90;
    if (target > maxUp * -1) {
        target -= 90;
        $('.sliderContainerInside').stop().animate({top: target }, 500);
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AJrqu/)

Answer (score 1):

If it's ok to use buttons `<button id="upBtn">Up</button>` try the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gWTj9/4/):

```
if (parseInt($('.sliderContainerInside').css('top')) - 10 > -maxUp) {
        $("#upBtn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

and when the animation is completed remove the disabled attribute

```
$('.sliderContainerInside').animate({
            top: parseInt($('.sliderContainerInside').css('top')) - 90 + 'px'
        }, 500,function(){$("#upBtn").removeAttr('disabled');});
```

Comment: Thank you again ebram. Going to adopt jimjimmy1995's solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated [demo that works](http://jsfiddle.net/gWTj9/5/).

As I mentioned in the comments earlier, the main problem is that you're determining the new position to animate to based on the current position of the animated element itself.  This means that if you start a new animation while you're still mid-animation, your offsets are going to get wonky.

The solution is to calculate all your offsets up front so that you can always know the correct offset to animate to regardless of the current state of things.  You can see this in action in the jsfiddle posted above, but here's the code for reference:

```
var $sliderInside = $('.sliderContainerInside'),
    $items = $('.optionMenu'),
    currentItem = 0,
    maxItem = $items.length - 3,
    itemOffsets = $items.map(function() {
        return $(this).position().top * -1 + 10 + 'px';
    }).get();

$("#upBtn").on('click', function () {
    if (currentItem >= maxItem) return;
    currentItem++;
    $sliderInside.stop().animate({
        top: itemOffsets[currentItem]
    }, 500);
});

$("#downBtn").on('click', function () {
    if (currentItem <= 0) return;
    currentItem--;
    $sliderInside.stop().animate({
        top: itemOffsets[currentItem]
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the `queue` option of `jQuery.animate()` solve your issue ?